# JSF2 with EJB3 and JPA - how best to package

Tags: jsf-2, deployment, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0, packaging

I'm trying to teach myself a bit about EJB3 and JPA by creating some functionality that uses JSF2 as a front end, stateless EJB3 session beans to handle transactions and JPA to persist entities.

Ideally I'd like the EJB app to be on a remote server, and the JSF2 war file on a separate server and communicate remotely - thus simulating a distributed project. But I'd like them to share the same JPA entity classes (as it seems kind of pointless converting them into other DTO objects just for front-end use - so it makes sense to me if the JPA project is in a project of its own

What I'm having trouble understanding is how to best package and deploy the various components.
Would it be best to deploy:
1) on server one: an EAR file containing the JPA jar file and the EJB module on one server. But if I do this where should the persistence.xml file be located - in the jpa jar file or in the ejb module?

and
2) on server two:  a war file with the JSF application and the JPA jar file in the WEB-INF lib of this war. In this case, I assume the EJB interfaces will also need to be externalized into a jar file and included in the web-inf/lib?

or am I thinking in completely the wrong way?

Would appreciate any thoughts on what the best practices should be to achieve what I'm trying to do? Apologies in advance if I'm doing it all wrong...it's a learning experience!

Answer (score 0):

First JPA objects are managed by persistence context hence i dont recommend to pass around that object to web  layer. You may use JAXB objects to be sent to your web layer. JPA entity objects should be  read and set to JAXB object fields and return the same.

Its faster and easier than pojo mapping frameworks.